# Marklogic: Forwardslash in attribute

Tags: xpath, indexing, xquery, marklogic

Some of my attributes have a **forward-slash** in the value.  I have **XQuery** that attempts to match on the attribute.  However, I was recently changing indexing options and now the **XQuery** won't match on any attributes containing the **forward-slash**.  I don't know what index/setting that might have affected the comparison.  Help!

Used to work, but not longer works:

```
fn:doc()//model[@id='model/books/20']
```

This works fine:

```
fn:doc()//model[@id='model1']
```

Comment: Please show the document you're trying to match against. And, if you can, what index options you were changing.

Comment: The document is irrelevant.  The item in question is that the matched attribute contains a forward-slash.  It would no longer match after some the DB changes. The reason I asked the question is that I had no idea what index options I had changed.  I was experimenting with all of them.  I was hoping that someone may know what setting would exhibit that behavior. (Boo to the down votes.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a wildcard option that was set.

UPDATE:
Due to downvotes, here is the explicit name of the setting that fixed the issue for me:
"trailing wildcard searches" set to "false"